# How to extract Youtube channel email in About section using Youtube Data API or Youtube Analytics API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I Just want to extract Youtube channel email in About section using Youtube Data API or Youtube Analytics API, So how can I extract the email and bypass the captcha normally using the API

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The purpose of the captcha is to precisely avoid people using algorithms** to retrieve emails (in order to avoid spam). So API won't contain such an option (even if I would say that it should be the case in a very limited way).

I don't know how many emails you plan to get but if I were you I would make an algorithm opening all the about tabs of these channels and then you complete the captcha if necessary each time (opening tab one by one would make you less suspect) with something like **Selenium** you can just have to humanly manage the captcha and Selenium load the about tab, take the email, close the tab, load the about tab of another channel and so forth.

Note that some *companies* sell captcha verifications by making your captcha solved by other human beings.

Comment: I just wanna do it using the Channel id, not something illegal or if the api provides to extract the email of the channel normally

Comment: It sounds fair but has anyone tried it? It looks just so simple to my eyes.

Comment: I don't think there is that much additional limitations (I might be wrong) however you have to understand that you will lose a precious human time to complete many captchas if you are looking for many emails.