# Is there a way for me to obtain a youtubers email address using the youtube data api v3

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was building a website which required for youtubers to login to my website and for me to know how many subscribers they have, I found out how I can find the subscribers in the API documentation however I needed their email too (whether this is the email with which they created their account or their business email). I couldn't find any answer to this in the documentation so I'm proposing this question to the YouTube help team however if you know the answer, please help me.

Comment: Duplicated with [71365699](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71365699)